# Fotorama show thumbnail with one image

Tags: thumbnails, fotorama

How to always show thumbnails in fotorama? Got a gallery with only one image and I want to show the thumbnail too and they are only shown when there are two pics or more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `enableifsingleframe` flag:

```
<div class="fotorama" data-enableifsingleframe="true">
  <img src="1.jpg"> <img src="2.jpg">
</div>
```